# wget to an IPv4 server from IPv6-only VPS

Tags: centos7, ipv6

I have a CentOS 7 VPS which **does not have IPv4, and only has IPv6 networking**. I've opened up Port 443 for accepting all TCP connections.

When I attempt to `wget https://www.litespeedtech.com/packages/6.0/lsws-6.0RC1-ent-x86_64-linux.tar.gz`,
it throws an error (which I believe is because https://litespeedtech.com/ is not IPv6 enabled):

```
Resolving www.litespeedtech.com (www.litespeedtech.com)... 52.55.120.73
Connecting to www.litespeedtech.com (www.litespeedtech.com)|52.55.120.73|:443... failed: No route to host.
```

When attempting the same for Google (which is IPv6 enabled) `wget https://google.com`, it succeeds:

```
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2a00:1450:4016:805::2004, 172.217.23.68
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:4016:805::2004|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

How can I connect to IPv4 servers from my IPv6-only VPS? I've heard about TunnelBroker but I'm a complete newbie and have no idea on what I should do to configure it.

Comment: I hope your audience for your web site has IPv6 connectivity, so they can actually reach the site. Unfortunately there are still ISPs that haven't deployed IPv6 for their users.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen My website is behind Cloudflare, so there's no issue for my audience on IPv4. The issue is that I can't access the IPv4 internet through my VPS.

Comment: Contact litespeedtech.com and ask them to switch on IPv6 for their webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change to Debian 10 (although this should also work for Ubuntu) and replace nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` to use [this Public NAT64 handoff service](https://v6tools.kasperd.dk/nat64handoff/service):

```
search blue.kundencontroller.de
options rotate
nameserver 2a00:1098:2b::1
nameserver 2a00:1098:2c::1
nameserver 2a01:4f8:c2c:123f::1
nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::4
nameserver 2001:67c:2b0::6
```

**Please note that the resolv.conf is specifically for EUServ VPS-es. If you're using some other VPS, copy and paste only the nameservers**

This allowed the VPS to (quite magically) access the IPv4 internet (yes, even installing packages from IPv4 vendor sites).

*This service is run by a single individual, who also has access to all of your IPv4 traffic and all of your DNS traffic. If you are passing sensitive data or are making a serious website, I think the best bet is to get a IPv4 supported VPS as of now. You can also use this to download some package you weren't able to, and then revert back to your original nameservers.*

Comment: Be careful with such a service. This one you linked to is run by a single individual and has low bandwidth limits. He also has access to all of your IPv4 traffic and all of your DNS traffic. He could also get bored and turn it off at any time.

Comment: This service is not replying at this time - either the remote site got slashdotted or its not accessible from the wider internet.   Great idea though, needs more resources behind it.  Perhaps something like OpenDNS could offer a similar service.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I completely agree with you! I'm updating the answer to include this information.

Comment: @Criggie It still works on my VPS though. I can't even ping https://ipv4.google.com without it.

Answer (score 7):

IPv6 and IPv4 are different protocols. If you only have IPv6 address in Internet space, you cannot connect directly to IPv4 only services. It's really short answer - "no, you can't".

TunnelBroker and other **free** services offers only tunnels in other directions, i.e. from IPv4 to IPv6 and not vice-versa as far as I know. You can set up your own tunnel on another host running dual-stack (both IPv4 and IPv6) or try to find some commercial service for that purpose, but this is out of scope of Server Fault and I doubt that this is what you need.

For downloading a file you can use other PC and just transfer it to your IPv6 box over SSH.

Comment: And, you should complain to any web site that still isn't serving on IPv6. It's 2020; they're many years overdue to start doing this. The website that the OP tried to reach is on AWS, so they really have no excuse; they could have IPv6 up in about five minutes. The problem the OP had is just going to get worse and worse for everyone as more time passes.

Comment: And it is pretty shameful for a web server software provider not to support IPv6 on download server. I wonder how the web server IPv6 support works then...

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I abanoned GitHub and moved close to a dozen repos to (self-hosted) GitLab, precisely because they didn't support IPv6 (and STILL DON'T) and I have IPv6-only VMs that could not check out from GitHub. But GitLab supports it fine, both on their self-hosted software and their hosted offerings.... Surprisingly GitHub actually got themselves a /44 and a /29 years ago, but have just been sitting on it.

Comment: Ive personally had a lot of issues implementing ipv6, mainly with upstream networking as either the hardware doesnt fully support ipv6, or their internal software starts acting strange. In this case with AWS they should just implement aws but for a lot of service providers they are bound to upstreams which have a lower priority for ipv6 ("It has no ROI"). Its a layered cake.

Answer (score 1):

Using direct Wget is not the only solution to get installation packages to your server. As the IPv6 only network works perfectly fine for your use case (a site behind Cloudflare), I wouldn't try and use any hacks for getting IPv4 connectivity even temporarily, but **use other ways to transfer the data**:

1. Use an intermediate server with both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity and mirror the packate there.

   ```
   user@intermediate:/var/www$ wget https://ipv4only.example.com/packages/install.tar.gz

   user@vps:~$ wget https://intermediate.example.net/install.tar.gz
   ```
2. If you already have SSH connection to the server, you could probably also use SFTP (*SSH File Transfer Protocol*) for uploading the package instead of directly downloading it.
3. Configure your Wget to use a HTTPS proxy in  `~/.wgetrc` (or global `/etc/wgetrc`):

   ```
   https_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
   ```

   You could use any proxy that supports IPv6 and HTTPS and you are willing to trust. However, I would still check the integrity of the file by comparing MD5 sums (`md5sum install.tar.gz`).